# Regex for masking data

Tags: regex, replace

I am trying to implement regex for a JSON Response on sensitive data.

JSON response comes with AccountNumber and AccountName.

Masking details are as below.

```
accountNumber Before: 7835673653678365
accountNumber Masked: 783567365367****

accountName Before : chris hemsworth
accountName Masked : chri* *********
```

I am able to match above if I just do `[0-9]{12}` and `(?![0-9]{12})`, when I replace this, it is replacing only with *, but my regex is not producing correct output.

How can I produce output as above from regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you want is to mask characters except first N characters, don't think you really a complicated regex. For ignoring first N characters and replacing every character there after with `*`, you can write a generic regex like this,

```
(?<=.{N}).
```

where N can be any number like 1,2,3 etc. and replace the match with `*`

The way this regex works is, it selects every character which has at least N characters before it and hence once it selects a character, all following characters also get selected.

For e.g in your `AccountNumber` case, N = 12, hence your regex becomes,

```
(?<=.{12}).
```

**[Regex Demo for AccountNumber masking](https://regex101.com/r/NHcSFf/1)**

Java code,

```
String s = "7835673653678365";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<=.{12}).", "*"));
```

Prints,

```
783567365367****
```

And for `AccountName` case, N = 4, hence your regex becomes,

```
(?<=.{4}).
```

**[Regex Demo for AccountName masking](https://regex101.com/r/Qg6oKB/1)**

Java code,

```
String s = "chris hemsworth";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(?<=.{4}).", "*"));
```

Prints,

```
chri***********
```

Comment: Thanks Puspesh, With your regex i am able to solve this, The only issue was with replace, as json data, it was replacing the end " from string too, So i have added regex like this (?!^).(?!$)(?=.{6}). and that is working for JSON

Comment: @KaranChaudhary: Great that you've already tweaked the regex as you needed :). Also in your regex, I think you can remove this part `(?!$)` as it looks redundant.

Answer (score 1):

If you match `[0-9]{12}` and replace that directly with a single asterix you are left with `accountNumber Before: *8365`

There is no programming language listed, but one option to replace the digits at the end is to use a positive lookbehind to assert what is on the left are 12 digits followed by a positive lookahead to assert what is on the right are 0+ digits followed by the end of the string.

Then in the replacement use `*`

If the value of the json exact the value of `chris hemsworth` and `7835673653678365` you can omit the positive lookaheads `(?=\d*$)` and `(?=[\w ]*$)` which assert the end of the string for the following 2 expressions.

Use the versions with the positive lookahead if the data to match is at the end of the string and the string contains more data so you don't replace more matches than you would expect.

```
(?<=[0-9]{12})(?=\d*$)\d
```

In Java:

```
(?<=[0-9]{12})(?=\\d*$)\\d
```

- `(?<=[0-9]{12})` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left are 12 digits
- `(?=\d*$)` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right are 0+ digits and assert the end of the string
- `\d` Match a single digit

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qqMUFx/1)

Result:

> 783567365367****

For the account name you might do that with 4 word characters `\w` but this will also replace the whitespace with an asterix because I believe you can not skip matching that space in one regex.

```
(?<=[\w ]{5})(?=[\w ]*$)[\w ]
```

In Java

```
(?<=[\\w ]{4})(?=[\\w ]*$)[\\w ]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DsOl65/1)

Result

> chri***********

Comment: Thanks!!! i am using java...this works fine online, but in java its not working it seems

Comment: @KaranChaudhary In Java you have to double escape the backslashes like `\\d` and `\\w` like `(?<=[0-9]{12})(?=\\d*$)\\d` and `(?<=[\\w ]{4})(?=[\\w ]*$)[\\w ]`